# multiclass-segemenratation using pytorch and unet

Tags: pytorch, multiclass-classification, unet-neural-network

I am doing landuse classification with 4 classes and as an output from softmax function of unet model i gained output of [8,4,128,128] and my mask image is [8,1,128,128] so to calculate loss I used nn.cross entropy function should i have to make any modification for good results as I find the output of testing image was 4 channels images which are not like mask image.``

Comment: Could you rephrase the question, I personaly dont understand it

Comment: shape of prediction is [8,4,128,128] and target's is [8,1,128,128] and prediction represents proabilities of being 4 classes ,how should i pass these values to cross entropy?

Comment: please help me!!